# Extracting some files from a folder and creating a list of these files

Tags: shell, awk

I am currently dealing with a folder containing about 1000 files and I have to extract some filenames from this folder and create another file (configuration file) containing these filenames.

Basically, the folder has filenames in the following format :

```
1_Apple_A_someword.txt 
1_Apple_B_someword.txt 
2_Apple_A_someword.txt 
2_Apple_B_someword.txt 
3_Apple_A_someword.txt 
3_Apple_B_someword.txt
```

and so on up until

```
1000_Apple_A_someword.txt
1000_Apple_B_someword.txt
```

I just want to extract out all files which have "Apple_A" in them. Also, I want to create another file which has 'labels' (Unix variables) for each of these "Apple_A" files whose values are the names of the files. Also, the 'labels' are part of the filenames (everything up until the word "Apple") For example,

```
1_Apple=1_Apple_A_someword.txt
2_Apple=2_Apple_A_someword.txt
3_Apple=3_Apple_A_someword.txt
```

and so on...till

```
1000_Apple=1000_Apple_A_someword.txt
```

Could you tell me a one-line Unix command that does this ? Maybe using "awk" and "sed"

Comment: [Same question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592513/extracting-a-list-of-files-and-creating-a-new-file-containing-this-list)

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this in two steps.

Create a file called `all_apple_a.dat` listing all files with "Apple_A" in the filename:

```
ls | grep Apple_A > all_apple_a.dat
```

Create a file called `labelled_apples.dat` which 'labels' your filenames:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+_Apple)(.*)/\1=\1\2/' all_apple_a.dat > labelled_apples.dat
```

Comment: It's much better to use `ls *Apple_A*` instead of `ls | grep Apple_A`.

Comment: @rush - Oh? Why is that?

Comment: here is the answer: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @rush - Thanks for the globbing notation. It's a good point, and you're right that it is better. I'm aware of that (good) article, and I agree. But I'll note that unless you're putting newlines in your filenames (in which case you have other problems), there isn't really any issue with grepping here, especially for simple command line tasks that are not scripts.

Comment: anyway one command is always better than two (: